# How to open a deep link sent in notification? - React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I've successfully implemented deep links in my project. Tested it as per the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#test-deep-linking-on-ios).

Now I'd like to open a deep link sent in a notification. How to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution, can open links with RN's [Linking.openURL()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#open-links-and-deep-links-universal-links).